# Excel текст не помещается в ячейку

Tags: python, django, excel, openpyxl

Сериализую данные из таблицы БД в excel с помощью `django.core.serializers.base`  и `openpyxl`. В базе данных попадаются очень длинные строки, которые не помещаются в ячейку Excel (ограничение 32767 символов в ячейке). А мне потом их обрабатывать в Excel и снова вносить в базу данных. Возникает ошибка. Подскажите элегантный способ разбить данные по ячейкам, а потом их собрать в одну при десериализации. Вот код, который вносит данные в таблицу:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook as XLSX_Workbook # считывание и записывание в файлы.xlsx
...
self.wb = XLSX_Workbook()
self.count = 0
self.ws = self.wb.active
self.ws.title = obj._meta.verbose_name[:20]
for field in obj._meta.fields:
    head_name = field.verbose_name
...
self.ws.cell(row = self.count+1, column = self.names[field.name]['column']).value = field.value_to_string(obj)
...
self.wb.save(self.stream)
```

Comment: Если их надо обрабатывать в excel, то, боюсь, универсального решения нет. Можно просто зарезервировать для колонок с большими данными несколько ячеек, но будет ли это удобно при обработке в excel - непонятно.

Comment: Excel - это инструмент, используемый человеком. Как человек будет читать такие большие таблицы? Такое разве что в качестве наказания можно придумать. Если человек в обработке данных не учавствует, то нужно искать иное решение, независимо от того, получиться у вас поместить столько информации в xls или нет.

Comment: В задании указан xlsx, ничего не попишешь. Скорее всего, поле с большими данными менять не будут, но данные в остальных ячейках могут поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, таблица из реляционной БД отлично ложится в xlsx файл - таблица-то плоская. Если у вас в БД лежат такие большие значения - это повод задуматься, а все ли с ней в порядке. Во-вторых, лучше дать пользователям какой-нибудь простенький Web-интерфейс для изменения данных, чем организовывать процесс БД -> Excel -> БД. Взяв какой-нибудь Django можно сбацать простую форму натурально за пару минут.

В общем случае можно выделить отдельную страницу под длинные данные, а пользователям показывать "указатели" - адреса на этой странице. Будет похоже на страницу памяти, где размер данных - 10 Кб. И указатель, что указывает на начало массива. Формат такого указателя можно придумать любой. Например, REF 0x00000000. REF - ключевое слово для опознания и адрес, который направляет нас на нужную строку. Соответсвенно, если размер данных более 10 Кб, то вместо них оставляем указатель. Если нет, то пишем сами данные. Схематично такой XLS файл можно представить так:

```
A     B        C               D
Имя   Баланс   Комментарий     Дата
Вася  100      Вася хороший    06.07.2016
Иван  200      REF 0x00000003  32.13.1990  -- Направит на 3 строку, и вытащит 20 Kb данных.
```

И страница для данных:

```
A            B                 C
Data1_10Kb   Data1_next_10Kb   Data1_next_10_kb
Data2_10Kb
Data3_10Kb   Data3_10kb
```

Таким образом, при загрузке таблицы, встретив в какой-либо ячейке REF + адрес, парсер поймет, что сами данные сидят в отведенной для них тюряге и последовательно проверяя нужную строку вытащит все, что было сохранено. Тут даже можно говорить "о расширяемости" - если для каждой страницы тоже есть ограничение по количеству символов, то можно создавать новые страницы и отображать это в адресе.